# Cocoa AES Encryption NSData and Bytearrays

Tags: cocoa, encryption, encoding, aes, nsdata

I'm using the following code to encrypt files in cocoa:

```
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
   // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
   char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
   bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

   // fetch key data
   [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

       //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
   //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
   //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
   size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
   void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

   size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
   CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,     kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted );
   if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
   {
      //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on     deallocation
      return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
   }

   free( buffer ); //free the buffer
   return nil;
}
```

And wrote this for the connection to the file:

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"rtf"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSString *key = [withFileKey stringValue];
    NSString *newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *encrypted = [newStr AES256EncryptWithKey:key];

    NSLog(@"File encryption:%@", encrypted);

    [filePathName setStringValue:filePath];


    if (!data) {

        NSLog(@"Unable to read file");

}
```

Basically what I did was first of all get the filepath of the file the user wants. Then convert the data in the file to a string. Then encrypt that string with the AES256EncryptWithKey: method. However, when I decrypt a plain text file for example, it returns a bunch of garbage like fonts and all that stuff, then the few lines I wrote. Something like this:

\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1138\cocoasubrtf100
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Bold;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 Hello my name is bobby bob\
\
\pard\tx560\pardeftab560\pardirnatural

\f1\b\fs22 \cf0 \CocoaLigature0 YAY!\
and I am awesome!!}

Shouldn't I be taking the data and then encrypting that (conversion to bytes), then convert the encrypted data and convert it to a string to display? I tried something like that but it didn't work. :(

Something like:

```
NSData *encryptedData = [data AES256EncryptWithKey:yourkey];
```

And then:

```
NSString *convertData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

?
Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears hard-coded to load `foo.rtf`. This looks like an RTF file. Where is the "plain text file" you're talking about?

**EDIT** We had a lot of discussion on this, so I wrote up a blog post about how to [correctly use CCCrypt()](http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564).

Comment: If you view it as plain text, the RTF formatting directives you're looking at are in there too. You're just seeing the guts of RTF on the output end.

Comment: So what should I do to take the "guts" of RTF on the output end? How would I just display the data that was encrypted? The String? Thanks!

Comment: The data that was encrypted was an RTF file. If you want plain text, start with a text file. In TextEdit, use Format>Make Plain Text and re-save it as a .txt file. If you want to convert RTF to plain text programmatically, that's a whole different issue, unrelated to encryption, and you should ask a new question.

Comment: There is no reason to turn data into a string in order to encrypt it. Encryption routines work on data, not strings. If you're working with sound files (or text files for that matter), just leave them as NSData. There is no "convert the data to bytes." Data *is* bytes.

Comment: Ok thanks. But the thing is I want to be able to encrypt ANY file whether it be sound, text, etc. And it does that, for I convert the data to a string, then encrypt the string. But when I decrypt it, it just returns a huge string with a ton of garbage ABOUT the sound file instead of the actual data. I need to be able to convert the data to bytes, then encrypt it, then convert it to a string to display, right? And in the decrypted version, it can't always display a string (only txt files), but must have the data that was encrypted. What do I need to do differently? Thanks!

Comment: So then I can have 'NSData *encryptedData = [data AES256EncryptWithKey:key];' And then convert that to a string?

Comment: Yes. Though you only need to convert it to a string if you plan to display a string. Audio files aren't strings, so there's no reason to convert them to strings.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help. Just one more question. So I did just that, and encyrpted the data. It returns like 8 character values like 866d788a 3763dbc. Is that fine? Does it need to be like: hm14ijdj28k+6TM7w+KWjMfGq8sLdw1Re6t0fs3p+hT177geu19CcdSFEUA4poafQu5iWqEXn5KsV3GoO0EdDjdI96btpbq5WSR8mnOanWI=

Comment: For plaintext of size N, the ciphertext length should be between N and N+15. Your first block looks like incorrectly cut-and-pasted output from describing an NSData (it looks like last digit was cut off). The second block looks like Base64 encoded data. You should not interpret these as "character values." AES takes data in and creates data out. It's all just bytes. You can only interpret plaintext as "meaning" something like characters or audio.

Comment: I have no idea what these two blocks are, so I don't know if they're encrypted or not. See this post for how to use CommonCrypto correctly. http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564

Comment: Thanks for writing that! It's perfect. Would the decryption of CommonCrypto be the same though?

Comment: Yes. As noted in the blog, I have left decryption as an exercise for the reader mostly intentionally (to make sure you actually understand what you've read), and partially because I didn't have a lot of time to write it. I'm still focused on getting my book out, which includes more memory-efficient ways to encrypt, and includes the decryption sample code.

Comment: Great, that would be a good exercise for me. Good luck on your book!